# Why does passing valid types to a typed array constructor generate an error

Tags: typescript

You can pass a number, an JavaScript native array, or another typedarray (and other things) to a typed array view constructor

```js
const a = new Int32Array(3);
const b = new Int32Array([1, 2, 3]);
const c = new Int32Array(new Int32Array([1, 2, 3]));
```

given that, I'd expect this typescript to work

```
function make(data: number | number[] | Int32Array) {
  return new Int32Array(data);
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDMBTA7jAkmKBmAJgEEAnEuATwAo8BKAbgFgAoUSWAIyRQ210NLlqAbQCMAGhgFJeALoMWbaDGDc0mHPmJlKVdXy2DdYydJhzaC5iwBmAVzDAoAS3AwAtnADWqKgBM4KDgALhQ7dw5UEhgAHzCIqOFZWIMBHQpaGABvFhgYElQoOxIwHg1+bSF-QLgrAF8YIA)

but it fails with

> ```
> No overload matches this call.
>  The last overload gave the following error.
>    Argument of type 'number | Int32Array | number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayBufferLike'.
>      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ArrayBufferLike'.(2769)
> ```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a known limitation?

Comment: The [typings](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L3502-L3504) for the constructor are written as a series of [overloads](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads), and overloads currently can only be resolved to a single call signature, not multiple. There's a longstanding request to improve this sort of thing at [ms/TS#14107](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107). Until/unless that happens you'd need to work around it.  Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: yea, that's it. What's the workaround? cast to any? cast to number? I know those will work to shut-up the compiler but they feel icky

Comment: Either of those would work, as long as you're happy with them (EDIT: oh so now they're "icky".  Which is ickier, type assertions?  Or merging another overload in like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w86rPm)?).  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Do you have any idea why that is not already part of the signature? Does adding that overload break something else?

Comment: "Why is it not already this way" I don't know and I'm assuming this is out of scope for the question as asked so I'm not inclined to put a lot of effort into researching it.  "Does it break something else" It really should not, but if you're really concerned about effects on the rest of your code base you might want to stick with a type assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript library typings for the typed array constructors (such as the `Int32Array` constructor, from [`lib.es5.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d045f18928f33bdae2c761615d04cf8aeffd90fc/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L3502-L3504), [`lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d045f18928f33bdae2c761615d04cf8aeffd90fc/src/lib/es2015.iterable.d.ts#L385), and [`lib.es2017.typedarrays.d.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/d045f18928f33bdae2c761615d04cf8aeffd90fc/src/lib/es2017.typedarrays.d.ts#L22), each addition corresponding to changes in the language spec over time) are implemented as a series of [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).  That is, there are multiple call signatures:

```
interface Int32ArrayConstructor {
  // from lib.es5.d.ts
  new(length: number): Int32Array;
  new(array: ArrayLike<number> | ArrayBufferLike): Int32Array;
  new(buffer: ArrayBufferLike, byteOffset?: number, length?: number): Int32Array;
  // from lib.es2015.iterable.d.ts
  new(elements: Iterable<number>): Int32Array;
  // from lib.es2017.typedarrays.d.ts
  new(): Int32Array;
}
```

And when you call an overloaded function (or `new` an overloaded constructor) in TypeScript, it resolves to exactly *one* call signature.  If no single call signature is appropriate, the call fails.  The type checker does *not* try to synthesize combined call signatures that would accept a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of the parameters accepted by individual call signatures.  There is a longstanding open issue for this sort of support, at [microsoft/TypeScript#14107](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107).  Until and unless that changes you'll need to work around it.

---

By far the easiest workaround here is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```
return new Int32Array(data as number); // for example
```

If you want to "fix" `Int32Array` you can [merge in](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) a more permissive call signature (remembering to use [global augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#global-augmentation) if you're in a module and not writing in ambient scope):

```
// declare global { // use this if you are in a module
interface Int32ArrayConstructor {
  new(x?: number | Iterable<number> | ArrayBufferLike): Int32Array;
}
// }
```

And then your original call will work without issue.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/PTAEBMFMGMBsEMBOlQHNYHsBG9agN6gigCuAzigC4AWAlmaLQGagCeGJoSKtAdl6AC2GcCViQAsACg+lSIibxoKAJK9KAZgBMAQUSJ4rAMIZeZSohLRKGRAWmhQvSAHcAFAA8A-AC4nJQSx5UAAfUBU5AyxxAB5eAKDEAD5Q0D0DVgAhEiYmeQAZWgBrSABKPzVNXX1DAG5pAF9pYiapaFNzAQBeJ1dw9W10wzcNUvq2jspQLFAe5xd+qqHWNwBtAEYAGlAtbY0AXTHpdrMp6FnehcrBmpX5xZuMta2dvcOjqSYSXmtaUyF4CU3OB4JR4H54oFgmFIYlVvtUtdqhlSvYpI5kJQSIh+PckctgaD4B8GqBpEA)